# django admin view on site don't use get_absolute_url

Tags: django, admin, reverse

I'm using default django admin. I registered models in admin.py,i define get_absolute_url in my models, but when i'm on editing form of my model button view on site redirect me to basic localhost:8000 no metter what i writing in get_absolute_url, it appears that admin didn't use it at all.

```
class Products(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
  slug=models.CharField(max_length=30)
  description=models.TextField(max_length=200)
  price=models.FloatField()
  created_at=models.DateTimeField()
  modified_at=models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return (self.name)

  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/foo/bar/'
```

decision:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from products.views import single_product
    return reverse(single_product, args=[self.slug])
```

Comment: Could you provide `get_absolute_url` method of the model?

Comment: No metter what i'm returning it redirect to the same page
    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/foo/bar'

Comment: Please show your full model. Are you sure that the method is correctly indented inside the model?

Comment: As far as I know you need to use permalink decorator if you don't use `reverse` inside `get_absolute_url`, but I may be wrong

Comment: Added my model. As for reverse according to the dock, it's better to use reverse, and i tried it, didn't help. I have feeling i missed something simple.

Comment: As i thought it was my stupid mistake.

Comment: I have the same problem. What was your mistake here? It might be of help

Comment: I don't remember exactly problem but i see that i used reverse. See updated question